# Convert Site with messenger to work like facebook

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, ajax, loading

Hello I'm creating a site at the moment (asp.net mvc) which has a div at the bottom side of the page that works as a messenger.

I would like to find a way to make the site work like facebook's chat. In other words, when a user clicks on a link on the site to load the content on the back however the messenger to stay in tact without loading again.

Will I have to change the site so every page is loaded with an ajax request? Also, I don't want to use iframes.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to have elements to stay on screen from page to page without using iframes to use ajax requests, something like load() if you're uisng jQuery.

Most sites that do it use some variation of hashbangs, so a page can be loaded by directly entering it's url, rather than necessitating a path through other pages.

To do what you propose has fundamental implications to the structure of the entire site, so if this messenger box isn't anything more than a gimmick, I wouldn't bother. I'd even go so far as to say that if you're not sure how you'd do this one thing, you shouldn't be trying to build a site around it.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont want your chat to disappear even for a moment with full site refresh, then yes, you have to change your page to ajax loading. It is not such a pain as it looks - for example use jquery to intercept all clicks on anchors, make ajax call to their href, and replace some "all-wrapping" placeholder div with the returned content.. Not very pretty usage of ajax, but it works, and your chat stays in place.